# How to manage overlapping key-presses in tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter

When trying to replicate Space Invaders in tkinter python, I came across a problem as when you hold down the a key moving the player to the left and then press space to shoot, the player stops instead of keeping going to the left.

I have no idea of how to even approach this problem as I am pretty new to python and tkinter in general.
The minimal executable code to replicate the problem is:

```
import tkinter  

class Projectile():  
     def __init__(self, x, y) -> None:  
        self.x = x  
        self.y = y  

    def move(self) -> None:  
        self.y -= 7.5  

class Player():  
    def __init__(self, x, y) -> None:  
        self.x = x  
        self.y = y  

class World():  
    def __init__(self) -> None:  
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()  
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self.root, width=800, height=800, bg="black")  
        self.canvas.pack()  


class Game():  
    def __init__(self) -> None:  
        self.world = World()  
        self.player = Player(400, 700)  
        self.projectile_list = []  
        self.shooting_allowed = True  
        self.world.root.bind_all("<KeyPress-a>", self.move)  
        self.world.root.bind_all("<KeyPress-d>", self.move)  
        self.world.root.bind_all("<KeyPress-space>", self.shoot)  
        self.rendered_player = self.world.canvas.create_rectangle(self.player.x, self.player.y, self.player.x+20, self.player.y+20, fill="red")  

    def move(self, event) -> None:  
        if event.keysym == "a":  
            self.player.x -= 10  
        elif event.keysym == "d":  
            self.player.x += 10  
        if self.player.x+25 >= 800:  
            self.player.x -= 10  
        elif self.player.x-20 <= 0:  
            self.player.x += 10  
        self.world.canvas.coords(self.rendered_player, self.player.x, self.player.y, self.player.x+20, self.player.y+20)  

    def shoot(self, event) -> None:  
        x = self.player.x  
        y = self.player.y  
        if self.shooting_allowed:  
            if event.keysym == "space":  
                self.projectile_list.append([Projectile(x, y, "player"), self.world.canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+4, y+20, fill="red")])  

    def run(self) -> None:  
        for projectile in self.projectile_list:  
            projectile[0].move()  
            self.world.canvas.coords(projectile[1], projectile[0].x, projectile[0].y, projectile[0].x+4, projectile[0].y+20)  
        self.world.root.after(10, self.run)  

Game = Game()  
Game.run()  
Game.world.root.mainloop()
```

Hoping for your help,

Luis

Answer (score 1):

Your script is only working by accident, namely the key-repeat "feature". i.e. when you hold a key, it starts "repeating" after a moment, meaning you get a lot of KeyPress events. However, this is OS dependent and apparently, it stops when you press another key. Also it means, that the movement speed might be different on each PC where you run the game, because the repeat interval is different.

See also here: [Tkinter KeyPress and KeyRelease events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215326/tkinter-keypress-and-keyrelease-events)

The right way to go about this is to "debounce" or disable the key repeat feature (see linked question) and handle repetition yourself.

- When the key is pressed, remember that it is now "down".
- When the key is released, remember that it is "up".
- Have a timer that timer that runs each x milliseconds. Use the `after` function for this. In the timer, move the player if the key is currently down.

This way, you are only dependent on current state of the key (up or down), not on state changes (events) anymore. Also, it is very easy to integrate other stuff that should happen continuously in the timer function.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to detect multiple keys at the same time. I think the approach at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39606019/tkinter-using-two-keys-at-the-same-time) is very smart. If I use his idea to your program, the whole code will be:

```
import tkinter  

class Projectile():  
    def __init__(self, x, y) -> None:  
        self.x = x  
        self.y = y  

    def move(self) -> None:  
        self.y -= 7.5  

class Player():  
    def __init__(self, x, y) -> None:  
        self.x = x  
        self.y = y  

class World():  
    def __init__(self) -> None:  
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()  
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self.root, width=800, height=800)  
        self.canvas.pack()  

class Game():  
    def __init__(self) -> None:  
        self.world = World()  
        self.player = Player(400, 700)
        self.projectile_list = []  
        self.shooting_allowed = True  
        self.world.root.bind("<KeyPress>", self.keydown)
        self.world.root.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.keyup)
        self.rendered_player = self.world.canvas.create_rectangle(self.player.x, self.player.y, self.player.x+20, self.player.y+20, fill="red")  
        self.history = []

    def keyup(self, event):
        if event.char in self.history:
            self.history.pop(self.history.index(event.char))

    def keydown(self, event):
        if not event.char in self.history:
            self.history.append(event.char)
        self.movement()

    def movement(self) -> None:  # This 'detect' function need to run forever, to detect which key is pressed
        if 'a' in self.history:
            print("Go Left! (a is pressed)")
            # self.right()
            pass
        if 'd' in self.history:  
            print("Go Right! (d is pressed)")
            # self.left()
            pass
        if ' ' in self.history: # Space
            print("Shoot! (Space is pressed)")
            # self.shoot()
            pass

        #self.world.canvas.coords(self.rendered_player, self.player.x, self.player.y, self.player.x+20, self.player.y+20)  

    def shoot(self, event) -> None:  
        # Do something complicated.......
        pass
    
    def left(self):
        # Go Left
        pass

    def right(self):
        # Go Right
        pass

    def run(self) -> None:  
        pass

game = Game()  
game.run()  
game.world.root.mainloop()
```

In the code, I create a list named 'history'. It records the all keys you are pressing. And I also define a new function named 'movement', it checks what keys are in the 'history' and excutes conrresponding actions like shooting, going to right.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I already fixed the problem in a similar way :)